# Group same strings in array and count them

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

This is an Angular project and I have data that comes from the server. I am creating three lists. I have three types of sentiment and each sentiment has a description

```
for (const sentiment of this.dataSource.allFavourabilities) {
  if (sentiment.sentiment === 'Positive') {
    this.positiveList.push(sentiment);
  }

  if (sentiment.sentiment === 'Negative') {
    this.negativeList.push(sentiment);
  }

  if (sentiment.sentiment === 'Neutral') {
    this.neutralList.push(sentiment);
  }
}
```

This is how it looks like when I console.log that.

```
coverageId:137
description:"Positive"
id:119
sentiment:"Positive"
```

In HTML I am listing this in three divs and the only constant is sentiment which is displayed as an icon, the description can be different. But client mainly types positive, negative or neutral so I get an ugly list with same data. I want to filter that so it is a matching string in the description and I have positive in the description like 50 times, in my HTML it should say

**Preferred outcome:**

```
positive(50)
negative(2)
neutral
```

and not

```
positive
positive
positive
positive etc.
negative
negative
neutral
```

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="form-item favourability-wrapper flex">
      <div class="column" *ngIf="positiveList">
        <div class="sentiment-label">Positive</div>
        <ng-container *ngFor="let a of positiveList">
          <div class="sentiment sentiment-positive ">
            <i class="fas fa-smile"></i>
            <div class="description">{{ a.description }}</div>
          </div>
        </ng-container>
      </div>
      <div class="column" *ngIf="negativeList">
        <div class="sentiment-label">Negative</div>
        <ng-container *ngFor="let b of negativeList">
          <div class="sentiment sentiment-neutral">
            <i class="fas fa-meh"></i>
            <div class="description">{{ b.description }}</div>
          </div>
        </ng-container>
      </div>
      <div class="column" *ngIf="neutralList">
        <div class="sentiment-label">Neutral</div>
        <ng-container *ngFor="let c of neutralList">
          <div class="sentiment sentiment-negative">
            <i class="fas fa-frown"></i>
            <div class="description">{{ c.description }}</div>
          </div>
        </ng-container>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this to a html element that shows the length

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let a of positiveList">
          <div class="sentiment sentiment-positive ">
            <i class="fas fa-smile"></i>
            <div class="description">{{ a.description }}</div>
          </div>
</ng-container>
```

to

```
<div *ngIf="positiveList">
    {{ '(' + (positiveList?.length || '0')+')' }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="form-item favourability-wrapper flex">
    <div class="column" *ngIf="positiveList">
        <div class="sentiment-label">Positive{{ positiveList.length ? '(' + positiveList.length + ')' : '' }}</div>
    </div>
    <div class="column" *ngIf="negativeList">
        <div class="sentiment-label">Negative{{ negativeList.length ? '(' + negativeList.length + ')' : '' }}</div>
    </div>
    <div class="column" *ngIf="neutralList">
        <div class="sentiment-label">Neutral{{ neutralList.length ? '(' + neutralList.length + ')' : '' }}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

maybe this works for you, you can use Array.length to get the count.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
<div class="form-item favourability-wrapper flex">
    <div class="column" *ngIf="positiveList">
        <div class="sentiment-label">Positive</div>
        <div class="sentiment sentiment-positive ">
            <i class="fas fa-smile"></i>
            <div class="description">({{ positiveList.length > 0 ? positiveList.length : '0' }})</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column" *ngIf="neutralList">
        <div class="sentiment-label">Neutral</div>
        <div class="sentiment sentiment-neutral">
            <i class="fas fa-meh"></i>
            <div class="description">({{ neutralList.length > 0 ? neutralList.length : '0' }})</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column" *ngIf="negativeList">
        <div class="sentiment-label">Negative</div>
        <div class="sentiment sentiment-negative">
            <i class="fas fa-frown"></i>
            <div class="description">({{ negativeList.length > 0 ? negativeList.length : '0' }})</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're asking for help, let me help you improve your code :

```js
this.feelings = [
  { name: 'Positive', sentiments : [] },
  { name: 'Negative', sentiments : [] },
  { name: 'Neutral', sentiments : [] },
];

for (const sentiment of this.dataSource.allFavourabilities) {
  if (sentiment.sentiment === 'Positive') {
    this.feelings[0].sentiments.push(sentiment);
  }

  if (sentiment.sentiment === 'Negative') {
    this.feelings[1].sentiments.push(sentiment);
  }

  if (sentiment.sentiment === 'Neutral') {
    this.feelings[2].sentiments.push(sentiment);
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- I'll let you append the classes to your convenience -->
<div *ngFor="let feeling of feelings">
  {{ feeling.name }} : {{ feeling.sentiments.length }}
</div>
```

See how the HTML got reduced ? We can even reduce the typescript further with this

```js
this.feelings: { name: string, sentiments : any[] }[] = this.dataSource.allFavourabilities
  .reduce((p, n) => {
    if (!p.find(feeling => feeling.name === n.sentiment)) { 
      p.push({ name: n.sentiment, sentiments : []}); 
    }
    p.find(feeling => feeling.name === n.sentiment).sentiments.push(n);
    return p;
  }, []);
```